# Starting Fish terminal from bashrc breaks standard terminal input

Tags: terminal, bashrc, fish

I've added a command to start fish terminal from `bashrc` and so far it was working ok.
I've just added this line at the end of bashrc

```
fish
```

But after I quit fish to default shell current input isn't displayed anymore, although pressing enter will interpret whatever was typed.
Is there any other way to start fish automatically without affecting standard input stream?

Comment: Show us how you start `fish` from your `~/.bashrc` file.  By "terminal", I presume you mean "shell".

Comment: Yes, by terminal I mean shell. Updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you exit the `fish` shell session, the `bash` shell that was starting up but that was "put on hold" while `fish` was running, continues to run.  For whatever reason, it leaves the terminal in a confused state (try `reset` or `stty sane` to fix that).

If you always want to run the `fish` shell instead of `bash`, then it would be easier to just change your login shell to `fish`.  You do this with the `chsh` command on most Unices.

If that's not possible, then rather than just running `fish` from you `~/.bashrc` file, use `exec fish` from somewhere in the beginning the file.  This would *replace* any interactive `bash` shell session with a `fish` shell session, and when you exit the `fish` session, you would not be left in a `bash` session.

Comment: Adding anything to bash_profile doesn't change anything for me, moreover this file wasn't even existing before.

Comment: @Johnny_D You mean `~/.bash_profile`? Well then you terminal might not be starting a login shell for you. The `~/.bashrc` file might in that case be the correct file after all.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `stty sane` or `reset` to get your terminal back to how you expect.

Rather than running from the bottom of `.bashrc`, you can configure your terminal to start `fish` instead of your login shell.

Comment: I see, but unfortunately I have to use bash from time to time as some script aren't working in fish.

Comment: @Johnny_D Note that whatever language that you use to write scripts in does not in any way need to be related to what your login shell is. Just like you can write and run Python script while using the `fish` shell as login shell, you can write and run `bash` scripts while using the `fish` shell as your login shell.